# ¿Cómo usar el render.js de MercadoPago con Angular2?

Tags: angular, mercadopago

Quiero generar un link de pago en un componente de angular2. Ya tengo el link (init-point). Más específicamente, hacer esto que dice [acá](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/related/render-js/).

Lo que probé hasta ahora fue:

- Pegar el código que dice que hay que pegar antes de la etiqueta body en el index.html.
- Agregar ese código en un tag script en el template del componente.
- Agregar el script directamente así:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js"></script>`

- Agregar el script como se indica en [esta otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular2-component-template/43559644)

Nada parece funcionar. Este es el código del template para mostrar el link:

`<a [attr.href]="paymentLink" name="MP-Checkout" mp-mode="modal" class="green-L-Ov-Ar-ArAll">PAGAR</a>`

También probé poniendo el link directamente con `href='<la url>'`.

Muestra el link correspondiente al tag `a` pero sin ningún estilo y no me lo abre en un modal.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3):

proba con lo siguiente a mi me funciono.

El boton que genera mercadopago consta de dos partes:

- Una parte que es el render del botón donde se incluye el código de preferencia.
- La otra es una funcion de javascript que carga la libreria "https://secure.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js" en una variable global de Windows llamada `$MPC`.

**PASO 1**
Una forma de utilizar esto en angular2 es cargar la etiqueta < scrip>< /script> del boton dentro del body de tu index.html

```
< body>
  <app-angular>Loading...</app-angular>

  <!-- Mercadopago -->  
  < script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){function $MPC_load(){window.$MPC_loaded !== true && (function(){var s = document.createElement("script");s.type = "text/javascript";s.async = true;s.src = document.location.protocol+"//secure.mlstatic.com/mptools/render.js";var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);window.$MPC_loaded = true;})();}window.$MPC_loaded !== true ? (window.attachEvent ?window.attachEvent('onload', $MPC_load) : window.addEventListener('load', $MPC_load, false)) : null;})();
  < /script>
< /body>
```

Esto ya generara las variables globales que podras utilizar para abrir la pagina de mercado pago en formato modal.

**PASO 2** 
En la parte de tu aplicación que desees pones la etiqueta del boton **sin el href** y ademas agregas una funcion llamada pagar(). Es decir te quedaría algo asi:

```
< a mp-mode="dftl" (click)="pagar()"  name="MP-payButton" class='blue-tr-m-rn-aron'>Pagar< / a>
```

**PASO 3** Finalmente ingresas el codigo del boton en el componente donde utilizaras el objeto global $MPC que incluye, entre otras cosas, la funcion `openCheckout`

```
pagar(){
 window.$MPC.openCheckout({
 url:"https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/start?pref_id=269515452-86c1210a-e241-4995-9c99-e68def4c1220",
 onreturn:(data)=>{console.log(data)} //Acá podes obtener el evento si cancela la opercion
})
}
```

Para darle prolijidad podrias meter esa funcion dentro de un servicio y que devuelva un observable con el dato obtenido en onreturn

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Esto me funcionaba perfecto, hasta que hace unos días empezó a dar el error `"$MPC is not defined"` cuando intenta llamar a _openCheckout()_. Te sucedió lo mismo?

Comment: Pudiste solucionar eso del $MPC is not defined?